# Angular 2 http request to Play REST server

Tags: javascript, json, http, angular, playframework

I'm implementing an Angular 2 service which gets JSON data from play framework server by http request.

http://localhost:9000/read returns JSON data like `[{"id":1,"name":"name1"},{"id":2,"name":"name2"}]`.

And here's my Angular service code (from this tutorial https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/server-communication.html):

```
import { Injectable }     from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { Hero }           from './hero';
import { Observable }     from 'rxjs/Observable';
@Injectable()
export class HttpService {
private heroesUrl = "http:localhost:9000/read";  // URL to web API
constructor (private http: Http) {}
getHeroes (): Observable<Hero[]> {
return this.http.get(this.heroesUrl)
                .map(this.extractData)
                .catch(this.handleError);
}
private extractData(res: Response) {
let body = res.json();
return body || { };
}
private handleError (error: Response | any) {
// In a real world app, we might use a remote logging infrastructure
let errMsg: string;
if (error instanceof Response) {
  const body = error.json() || '';
  const err = body.error || JSON.stringify(body);
  errMsg = `${error.status} - ${error.statusText || ''} ${err}`;
} else {
  errMsg = error.message ? error.message : error.toString();
}
console.error(errMsg);
return Observable.throw(errMsg);
}
}
```

But the request in browser looks like this:

```
GET XHR http://localhost:4200/localhost:9000/read [HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 5ms]
```

So Angular creates relative URL, when absolute URL is needed.
So could I...

1)Fix it in code.

2)Or make Angular 2 and Play run on same port.

3)Use JSONP or something else.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `http://localhost:9000/read`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason to your relative url is simply because you have a typo, which causes this. Instead of

```
private heroesUrl = "http:localhost:9000/read";
```

it should be

```
private heroesUrl = "http://localhost:9000/read";
```

No other magic should probably not be needed here. You might run into a cors issue. But since this is a playground, and not actual development, in case of CORS you can enable CORS easily in chrome. But this is naturally NOT recommended in a real-life app. But for playing, that would do just fine.

Comment: Thanks, this worked. And you where definitely right about CORS issue :)

Comment: Yes, I'm psychic :D jokes aside - good that it worked out! :)